# Firebase ArrayList with buttons update firebase data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an appointment management system for students and lecturers. I have an array listview which retrieves data from firebase. I included two buttons to change the status of the appointment to accepted or rejected. I could not find a code to update the firebase data on the listview when the buttons are pressed.

I'm actually new to android development so forgive me if I ask questions that are easy to answer. I've tried everything to find a solution to my problem but i can't seem to find one. This is an appointment management system where students could set up an appointment with their lecturers. For the lecturer view, I have a listview which shows all the request for an appointment made by students. Each row will have 2 sets of buttons which is to accept or reject the appointment. When either one of the buttons is pressed, it will update the status of the appointment eg; press approve button status turns to approved. The data is retrieved from the firebase real-time database.  My problem is that I could not find an appropriate code to update the status of the appointment when either the two buttons are pressed. I really need help for this. Thanks in advance.

This is for my activity.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lect_fragment_appointment, container, false);

    myrecyclerview= (RecyclerView)  v.findViewById(R.id.appointment_list_recyclerview2);
    myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    list = new ArrayList<ListView_Appointmnet_LectView>();

    SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("user_details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Appointment");


    Query query1 = databaseReference.orderByChild("lect_name").equalTo(preferences.getString("Lect_Name",null));



    query1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {

                ListView_Appointmnet_LectView L = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ListView_Appointmnet_LectView.class);
                list.add(L);

            }

            adapter = new CustomAdapter_ListView_Lecturer(getContext(),list);
            myrecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

This is my adapter view

```
public class CustomAdapter_ListView_Lecturer extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter_ListView_Lecturer.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;

ArrayList <ListView_Appointmnet_LectView> appointment_lectview ;

public CustomAdapter_ListView_Lecturer(Context c, ArrayList<ListView_Appointmnet_LectView> a)
{
    context = c;
    appointment_lectview = a;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_appointment_list_lecturer, viewGroup, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {

    myViewHolder.name.setText(appointment_lectview.get(position).getStudent_ID());
    myViewHolder.subject.setText(appointment_lectview.get(position).getSubject());
    myViewHolder.date.setText(appointment_lectview.get(position).getStart_date());
    myViewHolder.time.setText(appointment_lectview.get(position).getStart_time());
    myViewHolder.onClick(position);



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return appointment_lectview.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView name, date, subject, time, status;
    ImageButton approve_btn, reject_btn;


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appointment_studentID);
        date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appointment_date);
        subject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appointment_subject);
        time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appointment_time);
        status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.appointment_status);
        approve_btn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.approve_btn);
        reject_btn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reject_btn);
    }

    public void onClick(final int position) {
        approve_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Approve " + position + "is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });

        reject_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Reject " + position + "is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Setter and getter class:

```
public class ListView_Appointmnet_LectView {

private String start_date;
private String subject;
private String start_time;
private String student_ID;
private String status;


public ListView_Appointmnet_LectView() {

}

public ListView_Appointmnet_LectView(String start_date, String subject, String start_time, String student_ID, String status) {
    this.start_date = start_date;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.start_time = start_time;
    this.student_ID = student_ID;
    this.status = status;
}

public String getStart_date() {
    return start_date;
}

public void setStart_date(String start_date) {
    this.start_date = start_date;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public String getStart_time() {
    return start_time;
}

public void setStart_time(String start_time) {
    this.start_time = start_time;
}

public String getStudent_ID() {
    return student_ID;
}

public void setStudent_ID(String student_ID) {
    this.student_ID = student_ID;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user clicks on an item in the recycler view, you get told the position/index of the item they clicked on. So you will need to somehow map that position back to the key of that item in the Firebase Realtime Database.

A simple way to do that is by keeping both the value and the key of the snapshots. Right now your code is ignoring the key, only taking the value. So by adding an extra list with the keys, you can then look up the key when an item is clicked.

The main piece of code you'll need to modify is `onDataChange`:

```
query1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            ListView_Appointmnet_LectView L = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ListView_Appointmnet_LectView.class);
            list.add(L);

            String key = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
            keyList.add(key);
        }
```

For this to work, you'll need to:

1. Add a `keyList` variable to your `onCreateView`.
2. Give the `CustomAdapter_ListView_Lecturer` a member field to hold the key list.
3. Pass the `keyList` into your `CustomAdapter_ListView_Lecturer` constructor, and set the member field.
4. Make it so that your view holder classes can find the adapter, either by passing it into the constructor, or by making sure the adapter is visible within the scope of the view holders.
5. Look up the key of the clicked item by its position:

   ```
   public void onClick(final int position) {
       approve_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(context, "Approve " + position + "is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               String key = adapter.mKeyList.get(position);
   ```
6. Update the item based on its key:

   ```
   DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Appointment");
   ref.child(key).child("status").setValue("NEW STATUS");
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I'm really new with mobile app development and I'm very sorry but I could not understand part 2,3 and 4 of your question.

Comment: I unfortunately can't go writing all the code for you, so tried to use words that you can easily search for. For example, step 2 tells you to add a member field to your adapter, something like `ArrayList<String> mKeyList = new ArrayList<String>(); ArrayList <ListView_Appointmnet_LectView> appointment_lectview;`

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thank you so much for helping me :) I would like to apologize for having to put up with my lack of knowledge. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hey sorry, I forgot to ask you earlier but I have another problem with my recyclerview, when I update the status from pressing the button, the data is updated but it adds to the current list. Only when I go to another activity will it update the list. For example, I have 3 data in a list with processing status. when I press the button of one the list, it will update that particular list but adds to the current list. It becomes 6 data in the list but if I go to another activity and comeback, the list will show 3 with updated data. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Sorry, that's hard to say from this description. Have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and post a new question with such an MCVE for this problem.

Comment: It's ok. I will try to post another question for this problem if I cannot find the solution. Thanks again